# How to swap blue and red channel in an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am facing a little bit of problem in swapping the channels (specifically red and blue) of an image. I am using Opencv 3.0.0 and Python 2.7.12. Following is my code for swapping the channels

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("input/car1.jpg")

#The obvious approach
Cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#Manual Approach
red = img[:,:,2]
blue = img[:,:,0]

img[:,:,0] = red
img[:,:,2] = blue

cv2.imshow("frame",Cimg)
cv2.imshow("frame2", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am unable to figure out why the same image undergoing through the same(probably) operation is giving two different outputs. Can someone throw some light on what's going wrong?

Original Image
[image: The original Image]

Manual Operation
[image: The manual operation]

COLOR_BGR2RGB
[image: The cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB operation]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`red` and `blue` are just views of your image. When you do `img[:,:,0] = red` this changes `img` but also `blue` which is just a view (basically just a reference to the sub-array `img[:,:,0]`) not a copy, so you loose the original blue channel values. Basically what you assume is a temp copy just is not. Add `.copy()` and it will work.

```
img = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))

red = img[:,:,2].copy()
blue = img[:,:,0].copy()

img[:,:,0] = red
img[:,:,2] = blue

print("with copy:\n", img)

img = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))

red = img[:,:,2]
blue = img[:,:,0]

img[:,:,0] = red
img[:,:,2] = blue

print("without copy:\n",img)
```

results:

with copy:

```
 [[[ 2  1  0]
  [ 5  4  3]
  [ 8  7  6]]

 [[11 10  9]
  [14 13 12]
  [17 16 15]]

 [[20 19 18]
  [23 22 21]
  [26 25 24]]]
```

without copy:

```
 [[[ 2  1  2]
  [ 5  4  5]
  [ 8  7  8]]

 [[11 10 11]
  [14 13 14]
  [17 16 17]]

 [[20 19 20]
  [23 22 23]
  [26 25 26]]]
```

Note: you actually only need 1 temp copy of 1 channel.
Or you could also simply do `img[:,:,::-1]` this will create a view again but with swapped channels, `img` will stay unchanged, unless you reassign it:

```
img = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))

print(img[:,:,::-1])
print(img)
img = img[:,:,::-1]
print(img)
```

results:

```
[[[ 2  1  0]
  [ 5  4  3]
  [ 8  7  6]]

 [[11 10  9]
  [14 13 12]
  [17 16 15]]

 [[20 19 18]
  [23 22 21]
  [26 25 24]]]


[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]


[[[ 2  1  0]
  [ 5  4  3]
  [ 8  7  6]]

 [[11 10  9]
  [14 13 12]
  [17 16 15]]

 [[20 19 18]
  [23 22 21]
  [26 25 24]]]
```