# OpenCV swapping color channels: Is there an issue with this question?

Tags: python, opencv

I come across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538952/how-to-swap-blue-and-green-channel-in-an-image-using-opencv), and wonder if there is any issue with it.  The title says swapping GREEN and BLUE is desired.  The "obvious" solution is said to use `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`.

However, that seems to swap BLUE and RED instead.  In the ordering of BGR_RGB, GREEN is not swapped.  Am I right?

Comment: The title may say blue and green, but the question body and the code imply he meant blue and red. As for the BGR->RGB swap, you're right, G shouldn't  be affected.

Answer (score 0):

you can change places to channels too

```
import cv2
  
img = cv2.imread('images/test1.png')
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
img1 = cv2.merge([g,r,r])
img2 = cv2.merge([r,g,g])
img3 = cv2.merge([b,b,r])

cv2.imshow('1',img1)
cv2.imshow('2',img2)
cv2.imshow('3',img3)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```